# Ectopic prenancy probablity

Tags: probability

An ectopic pregnancy is twice as likely to occur when the pregnant woman is a smoker than when she is a nonsmoker. If $32\%$ of women of childbearing age are smokers, what percentage of women having ectopic pregnancies are smokers?

Attempt:
Let $E$ denote the event of an ectopic pregnancy and let $S$ denote the event that the woman is a smoker. So far we are given
$$Pr(E∣S)=2Pr(E∣nS),\quad Pr(S)=0.32$$
We wish to find $Pr(S∣E)$. From Bayes' law,
$$Pr(S∣E)=Pr(E∩S)/Pr(E).$$
I am replacing $Pr(E)$ with $Pr(E∣S) + Pr(E∣nS)$.
I am not getting why $Pr(E) = Pr(E∣S) + Pr(E∣nS)$ is wrong.
Kindly help?

Comment: Imagine if $E$ is some really common property, like "not being bald". It could easily be the case that 98% of smokers and 99% of non-smokers have hair. Would it follow that 197% of all people have hair?

Comment: You could say $Pr(E)=Pr(E\cap S)+Pr(E\cap nS)$.